# Customizing magento admin backend depends up in admin user login

Tags: user-interface, magento, admin, adminhtml

When a admin user login how to change the admin UI depends up on the user role, I need to change the admin UI and additional elements to it after login of particular admin user, is it possible to change the admin html UI ?

Answer (score 1):

Just check in admin

```
Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getRole()
```

Depending on this you can customize.

Comment: How to change the admin UI  based on this?

Comment: Depending on this condition you can change the templates as you wish

Comment: Can you give me brief idea, about changing the template and layouts

Comment: I want to change the entire admin UI, is it possible with this template change?